# Want to convert a rectangular image to hexagon image using HTML CSS JQuery with IE8 compatability?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

```
<div class="backgroundImage">

</div>

.backgroundImage
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left
  background:url('source.jpeg');
}
```

I want to convert the source.jpeg which is in rectangular shape to a hexagon shape before loading into the web page.Is there any way of converting into a hexagonal shape using HTML CSS and jquery.I heard using SVG graphics it might be possible.I'm not sure of it.
It should be compatible in all browsers including IE8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but it seems to work - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/Z42m9/1/)
You can increase the size of the corners to make the hexagon instead of an octagon.
Put the picture in a div as a background.

Add the corners with the same colors as your background outside of the div.

It seems to work under IE8 (used F12 setting), but I can't promise it.

I'm sure others will come up with something more elegant.

HTML

```
<div class='bigdiv'>
    <div class='topleft'></div>
    <div class='topright'></div>
    <div class='bottomleft'></div>
    <div class='bottomright'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the corners have gradient effect which is tough to implement in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://creative-punch.net/2014/01/perfect-css-hexagons-size-using-transform-calc/). It describes how to create a perfect hexagon using CSS transform and calc() (which allows you to create it in any size and all you need to adjust is the height).

It uses background-color but I guess you could use an image.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.